# Difference between .zipWithIndex and custom index value in Scala

Tags: scala

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c")
```

If I would like to traverse list's each element with index.
There are two way to do this.

**Approach 1**

```
var idx = 0
list.foreach { str => ... idx++ }
```

**Approach 2 : *Found from the internet***

```
list.zipWithIndex.foreach { case( str, idx) => ... }
```

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not a functional way to do it.**

```
var index = 0

list.foreach { elem =>
 //do something with elem
 index += 1
}
```

In the above code following things are bad practices

1) mutable variable. (accidentally some one can mutate and not good in parallel & concurrent scenarios)

2) error prone. increment has to be done (if you forget incrementing thats a disaster)

**Functional way**

```
list.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (elem, index) =>
  //do something.
}
```

Index is magically given to the user. You do not have to worry about illegal accesses of the state, incrementing of index and is fool proof.

Answer (score 2):

`zipWithIndex` will create a collection of 2-tuples. Creating your own will give you a little more flexibility in what type of data structure to use for the output.

But it's not called the Standard Library for nothing.  Staying with established standards has many benefits: ease of code sharing, under-the-hood optimizations, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `zip` with `stream` to define your own indexes.

```
List("a", "b", "c") zip (Stream from 1)
```

It returns

```
List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

The above code returns a list formed from this list and collection[stream] by combining corresponding elements in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small difference you should be aware of and it's the fact that `zipWithIndex` trigger an extra iteration through the collection.

And this can be solved by using `view`.

So, instead of:

```
list.zipWithIndex.foreach { case( str, idx) => ... }
```

You should do:

```
list.view.zipWithIndex.foreach { case( str, idx) => ... }
```